# Database Clustering

Tags: database, laravel

My Application is built on monolithic architecture using laravel framework and mysql database

The application targetting that it will serve more than 1 million users and at its pick hour will face to be managed more than 50k request per sec.

I know about Load balancing. But i want a help about database clustering

i want to implement a master-slave topology but i have no clue how to start with it.

i found some resource about clusterControl https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol But not understanding the proper guideline

**Question 1 :** The Guideline for implementing Database Clustering.

Answer (score 0):

you can watch a video on how to setup DB clustering. It is trivial with ClusterControl. Just setup the hosts with Debian/Ubuntu/Rhel/CentOS and provide the IP/hostnames to ClusterControl and it will deploy a database cluster Active/Standby (MySQL/Maria, PG) or Multi-Master (Galera).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umgvVHHaBog

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).